# Изменение суммы в зависимости от chekbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть `<div id='pricesumm'>100</div>`

Есть с десяток чекбоксов

`<input type='checkbox' onclick=redSumm(23)>
<input type='checkbox' onclick=redSumm(5)>
<input type='checkbox' onclick=redSumm(23)>
<input type='checkbox' onclick=redSumm(18)>`

...

Нужно сделать чтоб при нажатии на чекбокс сумма в блоке менялась на текущую + стоимость указанную в чекбоксе.
При снятии флажка наоборот сумма блока уменьшалась на стоимость указанная в чекбоксе.

Подскажите как решить вопрос или хотяб в какую сторону двигаться???

Comment: Если ты время от времени но собираешься в будущем заниматься html+js то ОЧЕНЬ советую познакомиться с jQuery (http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/).  
Облегчишь себе жизнь, сократишь время и откроешь много возможностей веб дизайна. На самом деле все намного проще чем обычный js.

Если ты конечно еще незнаком с этим, я думаю мой совет много кто поддержит.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dekameron/3EFn6/

Answer (score 1):

**native JS**

Получилось немного топорно, но идея, думаю, ясна. А jQuery да, рулит.

```
window.onload = function() {
       var i = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length - 1;
       for ( ; i >= 0; i-- ) {
       document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].onchange = function() {
                var container = document.getElementById('pricesumm'),
                    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

                if ( this.checked ) {
                    container.innerHTML = +container.innerHTML + +this.value;
                } else {
                    container.innerHTML = +container.innerHTML - +this.value;
                }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Даже для [native JS], думаю, целесообразней собирать всю сумму в переменную, и писать ее после цыкла сбора, чем в каждой итерации дергать данные из контейнера

Answer (score 1):

Собственно зачем обходить все чекбоксы?

```
function redSumm(obj, val) {
    var summ = document.getElementById('pricesumm');

    if ( obj.checked ) {
        val = -val;
    }

    summ.innerHTML = parseFloat(summ.innerHTML) - val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery юзаеш? Подсказка как просишь в какую сторону двигаться.

```
//деиствие при нажатие всех чебоксов
$("label input:checkbox").click(function(){
//проверка какой чебокс нажат и проверка сосояния чебокса
$("#myCheckbox").prop("checked");
//деиствия на изменения
//
}
```